# How to query option in command PHP MongoDB driver

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want use combine `MongoDB\Driver\Query and MongoDB\Driver\Command`. But it does not work. Who can help me. Thanks!

```
$filter = ['column1' => ['$ne' =>'abc']];

$options = [
    'limit' => 1000,
    /* Only return the following fields in the matching documents */
    'projection' => [
        'column2' => 1,
        'column3' => 1,
        'column4' => 1,
    ],
    /* Return the documents in descending order of views */
    'sort' => [
        'created_date' => -1
    ],
];

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);

$cmd = new MongoDB\Driver\Command([
    // build the 'distinct' command
    'distinct' => 'collection', // specify the collection name
    'key' => 'column5', // specify the field for which we want to get the distinct values
    'query' => $query // criteria to filter documents,

]);

$cursor = $mgClient->executeCommand('mydb', $cmd); // retrieve the results
$arr = current($cursor->toArray())->values; // get the distinct values as
```

Comment: The options do not apply to the "distinct" command. There is actually a [direct method on the collection](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.distinct.php) so you don't need to run the raw command. The output of "distinct" is simply an array of the 'distinct' values for the provided field path. If you think you want other fields, then you want [`aggregate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php) instead.

Comment: I'm a newbie. Can you help me to revise the code? Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do? Show some sample documents and the result you expect to get from them. It sounds like aggregate but your expected result is unclear.

Comment: why don't you use the library instead ? "You should consider using the driver with the complimentary [PHP library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library), which implements a more full-featured API on top of the bare-bones driver"

Comment: @NeilLunn note that the link you'd mentioned is belongs to the Mongo legacy driver which is deprecated, also which will not make a sense with the MongoDB .

Comment: I want get 1000 record with 3 filed column2, column3, column4, sort created_date desc of collecttion. With conditional column1 != 'abc' and distinct column5.

Comment: @hassan Does not matter. You cannot do what it seems the OP is asking for with "distinct". That's the main point.

Comment: Please edit your question. It's unclear whether you mean distinct values of column1 only or across all columns. Please [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44561398/edit). I think you should just show us 4 documents, and the result you expect from those 4. We can worry about the 1000 limit in an actual answer